# How to remove lines in the selected text in textfield

Tags: flutter, dart

When I select all the text in `Textfield` there's a line between each lines of text. This line appears when I increase the `Textfield fontSize`.

Behavior

[image]

Expected behavior

[image]

**Edit**

Below is my `Textfield` code snippet. I made this as re-usable.

```
TextField(
      onTap: onTap,
      controller: controller,
      focusNode: focusNode,
      obscureText: obscureText ?? false,
      autofocus: autofocus ?? false,
      onChanged: onChanged,
      onEditingComplete: onEditingComplete,
      onSubmitted: onSubmitted,
      scrollPhysics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      maxLines: maxLines,
      minLines: minLines,
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
      textInputAction: textInputAction,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
      selectionWidthStyle: BoxWidthStyle.max,
      readOnly: readOnly!,
      selectionHeightStyle: BoxHeightStyle.strut,
      maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.enforced,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: fontSize,
        fontWeight: fontWeight ?? FontWeight.normal,
        
        
        color: color ?? Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      ),
      enableInteractiveSelection: true,
      decoration: decoration ??
          InputDecoration(
            isDense: isDense,
            border: InputBorder.none,
            icon: iconData ?? widgetIcon,
            suffix: suffix,
            
            hintText: hintText,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: fontSize ?? hintFontSize,
              fontWeight: fontWeight ?? FontWeight.normal,
            
            ),
          ),
    );
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet

Comment: @YeasinSheikh check the new update

Answer (score 0):

This is a font specific problem with your chosen font size.
For example if you change text style to this:

```dart
TextStyle(
  fontSize: fontSize,
  fontWeight: fontWeight ?? FontWeight.normal,
  height: 1.0,       
  color: color ?? Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
),
```

You will no longer see the spaces, check the description on height for more details.